# Как сгруппировать массив так, чтобы вернуло массив из массивов, которые содержат объекты с одинаковым свойством?

Tags: javascript

```
[
  {
     name: Denis,
     age: 18,
     addresses: [4, 2, 3]
  },
  {
     name: Ruslan,
     age: 21,
     addresses: [12, 1, 7]
  },
  {
     name: Alex,
     age: 19,
     addresses: [4, 3, 3]
  },
  {
     name: Denis,
     age: 18,
     address: [8, 2, 0]
  }
]
```

Есть такой массив, мне нужно сделать так, чтобы результатом было:

```
[
  [{
     name: Denis,
     age: 18,
     addresses: [4, 2, 3]
  }, {
     name: Denis,
     age: 18,
     address: [8, 2, 0]
  }],
  [{
     name: Ruslan,
     age: 21,
     addresses: [12, 1, 7]
  }],
  [{
     name: Alex,
     age: 19,
     addresses: [4, 3, 3]
  }]
]
```

Comment: Совпадать должно ХОТЯБЫ одно из 3ёх свойств? `addresses` тоже считается?

Comment: Нет, addresses вообще не волнует. Надо чтобы все одинаковые username группируются в массив

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function group_users(users) {
  let names = [];
  let new_array = [];
  for (let user of users) {
    if (!names.includes(user.name)) names.push(user.name);
  }
  for (let name of names) {
    new_array.push(users.filter(user => user.name == name));
  }
  return new_array;
}

let users = [
  {
    name: 'Denis',
    age: 18,
    addresses: [4, 2, 3]
  },
  {
    name: 'Ruslan',
    age: 21,
    addresses: [12, 1, 7]
  },
  {
    name: 'Alex',
    age: 19,
    addresses: [4, 3, 3]
  },
  {
    name: 'Denis',
    age: 18,
    address: [8, 2, 0]
  }
];

console.log(group_users(users));
```